# How to dynamically add formGroup to a template driven form in angular4?

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular4-forms

i am using template driven form, as per functionality i have to toggle the controls on user interaction.
**problem**

initially all my controls gets initialized to the form but when during toggle i have to hide one control and display another. how can i register the newly added formGroup to the form.

i tried this, but it is not working

```
this.form.controls.addControl('formGroup_VIN', []);
```

**note**: it is an requirement, that i have to use template driven form

**UPDATE 1**

suppose if i have something like this

```
<div *ngIf="vehicle.show">
 <input [id]="saId" [name]="saId">
</div>

<div *ngIf="!vehicle.show">
 <input [id]="saId" [name]="saId">
</div>
```

and on click of a button, i show and hide the form control, now my question is, how will i register the newly added control to the form?

Comment: Form groups are part of reactive forms, and not of template driven forms (or I don't see it in the documentation).

Comment: please see my updated question

Comment: Your edit doesn't make any sense. You're basically showing the same thing twice, and hiding either version of it 50% of the time.

Comment: Why? Either use template driven forms of `ReactiveForms` don't mix it

Comment: all i wanted to know is, is it possible to register the control dynamically when we are using template driven approach?

Comment: @LijinDurairaj no, it's not possible.

Comment: It is an interaction between component, service and HTML. Can you please elaborate on those components?

Comment: That edit/update is just dumb - If show vehicle then show vehicle, and show vehicle otherwise......

Answer (score 0):

You don't.

I would create `formGroup` that contains all controlls and only hide those that are not required to be shown right now (can be done with *ngIf).

Things are very similar with template driven forms. Your model contains all possible properties, you bind all of them using [(ngModel)] to every input and you only hide/show required insputs. Model stays the same so there is no "registering new inputs" etc as far as you are not using dynamic forms.

Comment: If you have a formGroup, which is dynamic, I don't see the point of "hiding" when you can simply append them on demand. Plus, it's kind of out of topic (but I won't downvote because the question itself isn't clear)